# Groovy 3 and use of underscore with JsonBuilder

Tags: groovy, jsonbuilder, groovy-3.0

I have the following code that works with Groovy 2.5.7:

```
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder

def name = "foo"
def builder = new JsonBuilder()

builder {
            _id name
            contactInformation {
                telephoneNumber("12345")
                emailAddress("foo@foo.com")
            }
        }

println builder.toString()
```

Same code with groovy 3.0.2 returns the following error:

*The current scope already contains a variable of the name name
 @ line 11, column 17.
               _id name
                   ^
 unable to resolve class _id
 @ line 11, column 17.
               _id name*

Replacing _id with id or '_id' solves the problem

Can someone please explain why this error occurs with 3.0.2 but not with 2.5.7?

Comment: What is your question? I don't see any in your post.

Comment: sorry... the question is actually why do I get this error with groovy 3.0.2 and not 2.5.7 ...

Comment: It's better to update the question than to add details in a comment. I edited your question so it contains all that is necessary.